# display list items one next to each other

Tags: css

For some reason I can't display one `<li>` right next to each other:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
.bg1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg2 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bg1">item 1</li>
  <li class="bg2">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

that code should produce a red page (because the first `<li>` has a red background)
I want to create a carousel with Javascript but before getting to that point I need to fix this. thank you.

Comment: You're giving the list items a width of 100%, so that will cause them to occupy the entire width of the container. In order to create a slider, then you will have to extend the width of the parent element `<ul>` to accommodate multiple 100% `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the `width: 100%` in the `li` rule: It forces the `li` element to be the whole width of its container (ul / body). Set it to a fixed width, a smalelr percentage or leave it out and just use padding similar to my example below.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.bg1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg2 {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bg1">item 1</li>
  <li class="bg2">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need all divs to occupy 100% of the screen and after that with JS I will try to change the position of the LI. how can I set 100% without using % ?

Comment: The container (ul) still occupies 100% width, no matter how wide the li elements are. Apart from that you can use `100vw` instead of 100%.

Comment: I don´t get it sorry. Can I get an example? are you saying that the container `<ul>` will be `100vw`. what about the `<li>` ? what will be their size if I want them to use the full screen

Comment: no, my last comment contained two different /independent statements. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, so I gave you two additional hints that might help - but I don't really know without seeing your real (complete) code

Comment: I want to create a carousel with 2 slides. each slide should be 100% x 100%

Answer (score 0):

you have to add something like this in your css code

```
body, html{
   height: 98%;
   padding: 0;
}
```

to give your body the full page size then give `li` who is inside body the full size that will get it from body size